# NodeJS: combination of post requests and socket.io

Tags: node.js, post, socket.io

I'm creating a web application which has two web portals, and a node server. First portal sends HTTP requests(POST) while the second web portal should show them. Then a user will type some text and send it back to the server through the socket and it should redirect it to the first portal. I've used socket.io for the communication happen between the second portal and the server, while the first one does it though post. I'm struggling with finding a way to receive the answer from the second web portal and send the answer back to the first one. Here's the code.

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(5700);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log("connected" + socket.id);

});

app.post('/server', rawBody, function(req, res, next){

  var question = req.query.question;
  io.emit('question', {data: question});

  io.on('answer', function(data) {
    var body = {
      response: "data.answer"
    };

    res.json(body);
  });
});
```

As I've found `io.on('answer', function(data)` is incorrect. But what I need is something like this:

```
io.on('answer', function(data) {
        var body = {
          response: "data.answer"
        };

        res.json(body);
      });
```

Could you please tell me how should I get the answer back from the socket and upon receive it, send the reply back to the first web portal.

Comment: This is really not a good structure for how you use http requests and socket.io.  You're mixing and matching in a not very good way.  I don't see any reason to even be using socket.io here.  Your "answer" with response should just be it's own http request.  Much, much, much simpler.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(5700);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log("connected" + socket.id);

  app.post('/server', rawBody, function(req, res, next){

    var question = req.query.question;
    socket.emit('question', {data: question});

  });
  socket.on('answer', function(data) {
    var body = {
      response: "data.answer"
    };

    res.json(body);
  });

});
```

Comment: You can't put an `app.post()` inside an `io.on('connection', ...)`.  That will create a duplicate `app.post()` handler for every new socket.io connection.  After the third socket.io connection, you'll have three identical `app.post()` handlers.